# how to issue command to server and issue a command with a delay for 5sec to DUT using single python file

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ssh, server

I want to start the linux server and issue a command wait for 5seconds and then issue a command on the DUT using a python script.

Is it possilbe to do within a single python script or if at all we use 2 python script how to do it?

This is what i am doing

1)I have set up the ssh login withut password - which is working fine

2)start the server with command "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa server_name@ip-address < command >" - which is working fine

3)wait for 5second - which is working fine

4)need to start the DUT with a command - Not working :(

Please help me find the solution using python

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by DUT, but commands are accepted by ssh command as another parametr:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa server_name@ip-address command
```

And if you want to run a command, wait and then run the second command, the easiest way would be:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa server_name@ip-address "command1; sleep 5; command2"
```